# Connot convert from 'int' Android.OS.Parcel

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, parcel

I am trying to use spans to change the color of parts parts of my text textviews. But I keep getting this strange error, like my colors aren't recognized.

this is my code

```
        var span2 = new SpannableString(beforeMisterX + misterX);
        span2.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.GetColor(this, Resource.Color.abc_hint_foreground_material_dark)), 15, 6, 0);
        lblMisterX.SetText(span2, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
```

The error is at this line:

```
span2.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.GetColor(this, Resource.Color.abc_hint_foreground_material_dark)), 15, 6, 0);
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjgH7.png)

I also tried this but i still get the same error:

```
span.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.HoloBlueDark), 15, 6, 0);
```

Comment: The problem is that you pass an `int`, while the method expects an argument of another type (the one mentioned in the error message you have attached.). Unfortunately, I can't help more since, I am not aware about `xamarin` and their api's. As a starting point check if you can convert the `int` to the type is expected. Regarding your question, please avoid to include links to screenshots, in which the problem you have can be seen, try to include all the information in your question, this makes it easier for your readers to understand the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForegroundColorSpan` expects a `Color`, not an `int`, `Color.HoloBlueDark` and the return from `ContextCompat.GetColor` are ints, so you need to convert it to a Color:

```
var color = new Android.Graphics.Color(ContextCompat.GetColor(this, Resource.Color.abc_hint_foreground_material_dark));
span2.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 15, 6, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the conversion formula!